# How do you remove the edit button in an active admin show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to remove the edit button on active admin show pages for any record except for those where the month and year equal the current month and year.

I was able to do that in the index with

```
  if (es.month == Date.today.strftime("%m").to_i) && (es.year == Date.today.strftime("%Y").to_i )
    span link_to 'Edit', "/executive_summaries/#{es.id}/edit"
  end
```

My executive_summaryies.rb includes

```
ActiveAdmin.register Executive::Summary do
  menu :parent => 'Reports'

  config.batch_actions = true

 . . .

  action_item :only => :show do
     link_to_function("#{ActiveAdmin::Iconic.icon(:document_stroke)} Print Executive Summary".html_safe, "javascript:print()")

  end

 . . .

 controller do

 . . . 

    def edit
      @run_js_functions = %w(ExecutiveSummaries.init)
    end

    def show
      @run_js_functions = %w(ExecutiveSummaries.accordion)
    end

    . . . 

end
```

The way the code is currently, the edit button shows in the titlebar (by default I believe) and there is a print button next to it.  (From the code in the show above).

How can I just show the edit button for records that are for the current month and year on the show/view page?

Answer (score 7):

First remove the edit button from all #show pages:

```
config.action_items.delete_if {|item| item.name == :edit && item.display_on?(:show) }
```

Then add it conditionally:

```
action_item :my_action, only: :show, if: proc { resource.year = Date.today.year && resource.month == Date.today.month }
  link_to ...
end
```

h/t https://hungnhotblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/14/conditionally-show-buttons-on-show-page/

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your `executive_summaryies.rb`, you should be able to do something like this which will remove the edit button totally.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Executive::Summary do
  actions :all, except: [:edit]
  ...
end
```

Now that the edit button is not shown at all, you could then add it back conditionally:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Executive::Summary do
  actions :all, except: [:edit]
  ...

  action_item only: :show do
    if show_edit_button?
      link_to 'Edit', '/executive_summaries/#{resource.id}/edit'
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously, the `show_edit_button?` method you'd have to define with the logic you want to use to determine is the button is displayed or not.  Also, you can use `resource` to refer to the current object.